# How to get only one boolean value when comparing multiple conditions?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, boolean

I am using this code to compare multiple conditions between dataframes:

```
    boolean = df1.EmailAddress.isin(df2.Email) & df2.DateTimeCreated.ge(datetime.today() - timedelta(90))
```

The variable outputs becomes a series with 'False' as the choice like so:

```
0
False
False
```

However when I run both conditions independently they output to `True`, which is the correct answer I am looking for. Why do both conditions default to `False`? and how do I only get back one result? for example `True`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pandas `&(and)` is `index` sensitive , since your 1st condition is from `df1`(will have the `index` same as `df1`), and the 2rd condition is from `df2` will have the same `index` as `df2`, which will make the answer wired.

```
cond1=df1.EmailAddress.isin(df2.Email)
cond2=df2.DateTimeCreated.ge(datetime.today() - timedelta(90))
```

---

Fix

```
cond1=df1.EmailAddress.isin(df2.Email)
cond2=df1.DateTimeCreated.ge(datetime.today() - timedelta(90))#change df2 here to df1
```

Comment: the fix works, but how can I use two different conditions in my IF statements to compare? Ideally I wanted one True or False

Comment: want to do this: if cond1 ==True and cond2 ==True: do something, but get error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` and have reset index on cond1 and cond2

Comment: @RustyShackleford so you want any ? `cond1.any() &  cond2.any() ` ? or maybe `.all()`, it depends what you trying to do so